# Создание нового пользователя через админ-панель

Tags: yii2, activerecord, users, password-hash

Нужно, чтобы админ имел возможность добавлять новых пользователей через админку.

Как в таком случае задавать *password* и *password_hash*?

Answer (score 1):

Напишите консольный контроллер для работы с моделью User

Answer (score 1):

В Yii2 есть для этого функция, чтобы задать пароль

```
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
}
```

Чтобы при авторизации проверить пароль

```
public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я для этого создал две модели форм (UserCreateForm, UserUpdateForm). Что в одной что в другой, одинаковые поля (атрибуты) для заполнения. В первой модели проверил атрибут $password на заполнение (rules = [['password', 'required']]). Во второй модели убрал проверку поля с паролем на заполнение и при сохранение обошёл запись нового пароля в модель, если поле не было заполнено (что бы не сбить старый пароль).

Также во вторую модель обязательно нужно передавать $id редактируемого пользователя, что бы получить его данные. Это было сделано через __construct().

Принцип почти такой же как в модели SignupForm которая создана по умолчанию в yii2 advanced.